# Formatting Compatibility Across Email Clients

Tags: email, format

I want to type up a resume style email in the body of a gmail message and was wondering how much of the formatting would carry over to the recepient. Is there a standard that email clients follow when parsing the format from another client?

Answer (score 1):

Standard? There isn't even an HTML standard (that's actually implemented in full) used by all leading browsers, so forget about a standard for the HTML subset that email clients choose to implement. There is a large body of HTML that's safe across clients, but specifics are hard to come by. These links might help you figure out what's safe:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018078/testing-html-email-rendering

Or they might discourage you from trying. My advice: do your best with a web page and link that:

http://picknit.com/resume